# Java - Weka exception: No training file and no object input file given

Tags: java, intellij-idea, weka

I have used the Weka GUI before, and I am now trying to use Weka in Java. I have been trying to follow [this guide on the Weka wiki.](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+Weka+in+your+Java+code) I have a file with "test" arff data, and another file I want Weka to try and classify, using that test data and a naive bayes.

I'm using intellij and not the command line. I would like to just code in the name of the files without running the Java via command line. I have tried to code in the path to the file and set it and an 'instance', and it compiles but when I try to run I get this error:

"No training file and no object input file given
Weka exception: No training file and no object input file given"

With a set of options underneath

I will give my code below for inputs- Note that I am a beginner at using this and it may be completely incorrect.

```
       public static void main() throws Exception{
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader("/my filepath is here"));
            BufferedReader testReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/my filepath is here"));
            Instances train = new Instances(reader);
            Instances test = new Instances(testReader);   
            train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);
```

This is quite similar to the stuff on the Weka wiki tutorial. My question feels like it should have a simple answer but I'm stumped. How do I get the Java/Weka to recognize that I have a training file right there?

Comment: Are you sure you are creating the `BufferedReader` objects correctly? You may want to check if you can read data from them using the `BufferedReader.readLine()` method.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean. Whenever I run this code I immediately get the error in the console. I tried reading the files the same in a separate java file- then filepath is correct and the info it prints is right. The "instances" class wants a 'reader', so I can't give it each line as a string? I am following the first section of the tutorial from the wiki guide.

Comment: If you're sure the paths are correct, then the only difference I see in the tutorial is that you're not closing your BufferedReader. Other than that, can you provide the stack trace or some more info on the error?

Comment: I have figured it out-  I was extending another class when I shouldn't have been, my main wasn't being run at all. Thanks for trying to help though!